# Which is faster in pandas, group by date or loop through date?

Tags: python, pandas

Say I have a data frame 'data' with a known date range called 'd_range' (about 1000 days),
for each day in d_range, I have maybe 1000 observations, which of the following is faster, or are they about the same?

```
for day in d_range:
    df = data[data.timestamp==day]
    # do some operations on df

for day, df in data.groupby('timestamp'):
    # do the same operations on df
```

Do both approaches create views from 'data' instead of copies? if so, my guess is the groupby operation has a bit more overhead cost because it needs to aggregate timestamp first, is that right?